# Force elements to be on the same line

Tags: html, line

I have this situation, and I want the the span2 to be always on same line of text, but text can start a new line if is long

```
<span1>
  text
  <span2>
   <img1/>
   <img2/>
  </span2>
</span1>
```

**So this is OK:**

Text img img

**This is ok too**

Text

Text on a new line img img

**But this is not ok**

Text

img img

How can I do it?

Basically i want the 2 imgs to be always on the same line of the text, but the text can go on new lines

Comment: Hard to understand your question but you will probably need to use flex or grid. Can you be more clear cause you say: "always like this: Text img img" and "never this Text img img"?

Comment: I fixed it, i had some problems with new lines in the post

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox model as such:

```css
.span1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<span class="span1">
  Text
  <span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  </span>
</span>

<span class="span1">
  Text
  <br />
  Text new line
  <span>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element)  and [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.